# Training Keras LSTM returns ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

Here is my training code:

```
OUTPUT_UNITS = 38
NUM_UNITS = [256]
LOSS = "sparse_categorical_crossentropy"
LEARNING_RATE = 0.001
EPOCHS = 50
BATCH_SIZE = 64
SAVE_MODEL_PATH = "model.h5"

def build_model(output_units, num_units, loss, learning_rate):

    input = keras.layers.Input(shape=(None, output_units))
    x = keras.layers.LSTM(num_units[0])(input)
    x = keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)

    output = keras.layers.Dense(output_units, activation="softmax")(x)

    model = keras.Model(input, output)

    model.compile(loss=loss,
                  optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate),
                  metrics=["accuracy"])

    model.summary()

    return model
```

and this is the error I got:

```
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer model: expected shape=(None, None, 38), found shape=(None, 64, 23)
```

Comment: You can't call the summary method before calling the model the first time (or fitting the model).
It sounds like you have a problem with the shape of the data. Could you provide some feedback on the data you are using?

Comment: @elbe this is a project for music generating using Music21 library. my data is 14 krn files. this is the tutorial source code: https://github.com/musikalkemist/generating-melodies-with-rnn-lstm/blob/master/7%20-%20Training%20a%20Neural%20Network%20to%20Generate%20Melodies/train.py

Comment: Your input data has shape (64,23) but you have specified input shape like this: shape=(None, output_units) which is incompatible.  @BehnooshMzd